# How to disable Eclipse derived markers

Tags: eclipse, rational-team-concert

Is there any way to disable the derived markers on generated java files or allow to checkin such files in Eclipse with Rational Team Concert?

Comment: Whats generating those sources? What's marking them as derived? Looking for something more specific than "Eclipse".

Comment: Maven-compiler-plugin generates them. Does it set the flag an not my IDE?